# Get element from giving URL with dom php

Tags: php

Building an MTDB DB with php, and need to scrape a specific tag from the URL.

Tag to get from url

```
    vars.disqus = '';
    vars.lists = [];
    vars.titleId = '35079';
    vars.trailersPlayer = 'default';
    vars.userId = '907791';
    vars.title = {"id":35079,"title":"Family Vacation","trailer":35097.flv,"timing":0.50sec}
```

I need the

```
"id":35079,"title":"Family Vacation","trailer":35097.flv,"timing":0.50sec
```

My code:

```
$html = 'myurl';

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); $dom = new DOMDocument; $dom->loadHTMLFile($html); libxml_clear_errors();

$xp = new DOMXpath($dom); $nodes = $xp->query('//script[@\'id','trailer','title');

echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the "Tag" is not a HTML format, its looks like some javascript code ~~
2. to resolve these string, simply via regex

   ```
   preg_match('/title\s*=\s*\{([^}]+)}/', $str, $matches);
   var_dump($matches[1]);
   ```

Comment: Thank you. In which line i can integrate this code ?